# Angular 2 subscribe stuck in loop

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire, subscribe

I'm getting one record from my firebase database and I'm trying to update it's value but my subscribe method is doing something what I don't understand. It looks like infinite loop. Some ideas?

Example:

[Multiple test1 values in array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkRMR.jpg)

Code:

Component method:

```
borrowBook(isbn) {
   var uid;
   this.angularFireSubscriber = this.af.auth.subscribe(
      auth => {
        uid = auth.uid
     });
   this.bb.getBorrowedBooks(uid).subscribe(
      result => {
        var books = result[0].books;
        books.push('test1');
        this.bb.updateOrder(result[0].$key, books);
      }
   );
}
```

Service methods:

```
updateOrder(key, books) {
    this.af.database.list('borrowedBooks').update(key, { books: books});
}

getBorrowedBooks(uid: string) {
   return this.af.database.list('borrowedBooks',
      {
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'uid',
          equalTo: uid
        }
      }
   );
 }
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is, what are your expectations and actual result?

Comment: @shusson I need only one update so in my database should be only 'test' value and one 'test1'.

Answer (score 0):

This problem normally occurs when you try to do an update operation inside a subscribe function. The Observable type is a utility that asynchronously or synchronously streams data to a variety of components or services that have subscribed to the observable.

Solution is to set a counter if you want the update function to run only once, otherwise it will run infinitely.

declare a counter for example

```
 counter:number = 0
```

then in your code

```
borrowBook(isbn) {
 var uid;
  this.angularFireSubscriber = this.af.auth.subscribe(
   auth => {
     uid = auth.uid
   });
 this.bb.getBorrowedBooks(uid).subscribe(
  result => {
    var books = result[0].books;
    books.push('test1');
     //check the counter here
     if(counter ==0){ 
       this.bb.updateOrder(result[0].$key, books); 
      }   
      this.counter++
   }
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @FelixRunye mentioned, it can be done better by using the power of rxjs like below

```
borrowBook(isbn) {
let isAlive = true;
 var uid;
  this.angularFireSubscriber = this.af.auth
.subscribe(
   auth => {
     uid = auth.uid
   });
 this.bb.getBorrowedBooks(uid)
.pipe(
takeWhile(() => isAlive)
)
.subscribe(
  result => {
    isAlive = false;
    var books = result[0].books;
    books.push('test1');
    this.bb.updateOrder(result[0].$key, books);  
   }
 );
}
```

This will also ensure that all the logic to borrow a book is effectively running only once every time the borrowBook is called